# Math question from calculus 2 course?

Tags: calculus, integration

Prove the following inequality:

$$2\sqrt{n+1} - 2 < \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \dots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} < 2\sqrt{n+1} - 1$$

This question was given in a calculus 2 course, just after studying Riemann's integral, so maybe it has to do with that. It has something to do with integrals for sure (although I think one side can be proven using induction). Please don't use more advanced math.

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that the function $x\mapsto \frac1{\sqrt x}$ is decreasing we have:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt k}-1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt {k+1}}\\\le\sum_{k=1}^n\int_k^{k+1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}=\int_1^{n+1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}=2\left(\sqrt{n+1}-1\right)\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt k}$$
and then we deduce the desired inequalities easily.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a picture. Think about $\displaystyle\int_1^{n+1}\frac1{\sqrt x}dx$, and draw the inscribed and circumscribed rectangles for $\Delta x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

With simple tools:

For the left inequality it summarizes the inequalities:
$$2(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})<\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$$
for $k=1,\cdots,n.$

For the right inequality it summarizes the inequalities:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}<2(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})$$
for $k=1,\cdots,n-1$ and then adds $1$ to both members. Obtain a stronger inequality than in discussion, with equality for $n = 1$.

Remark: Applied directly to the proof of inequality right mathematical induction is not efficient.